# c++ vector with max N equal elements' positions

Tags: c++, vector, max, equals

Can I get the positions of the max N elements (the equal max elements) using predefined function in STL?

A solution I thought of is:

```
vector<int> maxN(vector<int> original){
    vector<int> result;
    auto pt = max_element(original.begin(),original.end());
    int max = *pt;
    while(*pt == max){
        result.push_back(distance(original.begin(),pt));
        *pt = 0;//assumed that all the elements in original are greater than 0
        pt = max_element(original.begin(),original.end());
    }
     return result;
}
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Be wary of using `.index()` on a vector iterator. That's not portable. Vector iterators are allowed to be raw pointers if desired. For the index, you can use `std::distance(original.begin(), pt)`, or, since it's a random-access iterator, `pt - original.begin()`.

Comment: @OP, Could you clarify that this is correct? You want the indices of all elements that are equal to the maximum value contained in the vector, and to set those elements to 0. If that is what you want, you can make the algorithm more reusable by taking an iterator pair and returning a container of iterators instead of indices. Alternatively, do as `<algorithm>` does and use an output iterator for the results instead of creating a container. You can build on that raw algorithm to add the convenience features. You can also easily make setting the values to 0 not part of this algorithm.

Comment: To make it clear, if you state your requirements more clearly and completely, you'll have a very good question. At the same time, the title could be updated to be more specific to your requirements. You're very close to a great question.

Comment: @chris sorry, by `.index()`,I actually mean `std::distance(original.begin(),pt)`.  Thank you for your tips!

Comment: @chris
I want the indices of all elements that are equal to the maximum value contained in the vector,no more requirements.  What I thought is that, since `original` is passed by value, if I just want to get the indices of max N equal elements,no more needs after that,it is OK that I changed its value. But as I said, it is not a good/correct solution to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have found the max element, make another linear pass over the vector to find all the matching elements. Setting to 0 is not needed when doing it this way. The original vector is being passed by value, so setting to 0 was not being seen by the caller. This makes for a very clear implementation:

```
vector<int> maxN(vector<int> original){
    vector<int> result;
    if (original.empty()) return result;
    const int max = *(max_element(original.begin(), original.end()));
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); ++i) {
        if (original[i] == max) result.push_back(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

***It is more importatnt to implement clear and maintainable code than to attempt to extract maximal reuse from the C++ library.***

If your goal is to not use an explicit loop over the passed in original vector, but use some standard C++ template algorithm, I recommend creating a helper iterator to help you recover the index.

```
struct indexer {
    int i_;
    indexer (int i = 0) : i_(i) {}
    indexer & operator ++ () { ++i_; return *this; }
    indexer operator ++ (int) { ++i_; return i_ - 1; }
    int operator * () const { return i_; }
    bool operator != (indexer rhs) const { return i_ != rhs.i_; }
    //... whatever else is required for copy_if
};
```

Then, you can invoke `copy_if` with a simple lambda and a back insert iterator:

```
copy_if(indexer(), indexer(original.size()), back_inserter(result),
        [&](int i) -> bool { return original[i] == max; });
```

*However, this is more obscure than the straightforward loop presented above.*

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you for posting 2 solutions. At that time, I just want to reuse the C++ library rather than considering maintainability. Thank you for your tips!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your exact requirements:

`std::max_element` gives you the maximum element. `std::copy_if` can be used to copy all elements equal to the maximum (and limit the maximum number if required, e.g. using a lambda).

`std::nth_element` partially sorts a range (e.g. your vector) such the first n entries are equal or less to anything that follows. The first n elements are not sorted themselves. And it is not a stable partition.

`std::partial_sort` gives you the same, but the first n elements are sorted. Again, not a stable partition/sort.

Combine `std::nth_element` + `std::stable_partition` + `std::stable_sort` if you need a stable selection of the first n elements and you want them stably sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP seems to want to return the indices of all the elements that are equal to the maximum value in the vector -- quite different from the title of the question and the description in the question.

Comment: @RSahu It depends on whether the question is correct or the code sample is correct :-)

Comment: @RSahu @ Rumburak the code sample is correct.I am sorry for the vague title.

Answer (score 0):

As variant (can check on a [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int>elems = {10, 20, 10, 30, 5, 30, 8, 30, 18, 12};
    for(size_t i=0; i<elems.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(elems[i+1] > elems[i]) { elems.erase(elems.begin()+i); i=-1;}
            else if(elems[i+1] < elems[i]) { elems.erase(elems.begin()+i+1); i=-1;}            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your original with indices, take the Nth element-approach, and strip off the indices again (test on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/6hti)):

```
template<typename T, typename less = std::greater<T>>
std::vector<int> max_indices(
     int N,
     const std::vector<T> &original,
     less predicate = less())
{
    auto decorated = with_indices(original);

    // the gist of the problem
    const auto nth = std::next(begin(decorated), N);
    std::nth_element(begin(decorated), nth, end(decorated),
                     with_indices(predicate));
    std::sort(begin(decorated), nth,
                     with_indices(predicate));        
    decorated.erase(nth, end(decorated));

    return indices(decorated);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ {1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} };

    auto m = max_indices(4, values);
    assert(4u == m.size());
    assert(9 == m[0]);
    assert(8 == m[1]);
    assert(7 == m[2]);
    assert(6 == m[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Where these functions do the decorating/undecorating:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::pair<T, int>> with_indices(const std::vector<T> &original)
{
    std::vector< std::pair<T, int> > decorated;
    std::transform(begin(original), end(original), std::back_inserter(decorated),
        [index = 0](T t) mutable {
        return std::make_pair(t, index++);
    });
    return decorated;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<int> indices(const std::vector<std::pair<T, int>> &original)
{
    std::vector<int> undecorated;
    std::transform(begin(original), end(original), std::back_inserter(undecorated),
        [](auto p) mutable {
        return p.second;
    });
    return undecorated;
}

template<typename Function>
auto with_indices(Function f)
{
    return [&](auto... args) {
        return f(args.first...);
    };
}
```